# Socket.io and Redis Pub/Sub not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, socket.io, publish-subscribe

Hello guys i would like to figure out what is the error in my code, my code is about socket.io and redis pub/sub it is my first time to try this, I hope you can help me guys.

This is my **index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script> 
        var socket = new io.Socket();
        socket.connect();

        socket.on('connection', function (socket) {
            console.log('Connected');
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', function (socket) {
            console.log('Disconnected');
        });
    </script>
    <center>
    <h1>Test Page</h1>
    </center>
</html>
```

This is my **app.js**

```
var redis = require('redis');
var app = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
var client = redis.createClient();
var pub = redis.createClient();
var sub = redis.createClient();

app.listen(1234);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){
    sub.on('subscribe', function (channel){
        pub.publish('Pub','Test Message 1');
        pub.publish('Pub','Test Message 2');
        pub.publish('Pub','Test Message 3');
    });
    sub.on('message', function (channel, message) {
        console.log(channel + ':' + message);
    sub.unsubscribe();
    pub.end();
    sub.end();
    });
    sub.incr('Channel Test');
    sub.incr('Pub');
});
```

I hope you can help me fix this code. Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see many errors in your code :

- in index.html, you should connect to `http://localhost:1234/`, because it's defined in your server code.
- `var client` is not used in app.js
- `sub` is never subscribing to something. You need to subscribe to a channel
- A connection in `subscriber mode` can not send commands to redis : only commands that modify the subscription set are valid
- `sub.incr` will never publish a message : you have to call publish.
- do not call `pub.end()` or `sub.end()` because the connection will be closed.
- do not add an handler to event `message` under connection event : memory leak

I don't know exactly what do you want to do but here is an updated version :

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <script src="http://localhost:1234/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1234/');

        socket.on('connection', function (socket) {
            console.log('Connected');
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', function (socket) {
            console.log('Disconnected');
        });
    </script>
    <center>
    <h1>Test Page</h1>
    </center>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var redis = require('redis');
var app = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
var pub = redis.createClient();
var sub = redis.createClient();

app.listen(1234);

sub.subscribe('Pub');//subscribe to Pub channel
sub.on('message', function (channel, message) {
    console.log(channel + ':' + message);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    pub.publish('Pub', 'New Connection');
    pub.incr('Channel Test');   //increment 'Channel Test' but do not publish messages
    pub.incr('Pub');            //increment 'Pub' but do not publish messages
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see you set redis as store in socket.io server. Some example I did for your reference:

```
// start up express server along with socket.io
var express = require('express');
var server = express();
var socket = require('socket.io');
var io = socket.listen(server);

// socket.io
io.set('store', new socket.RedisStore);

// set-up connections...
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

        io.emit('an event sent to all connected clients');

        socket.on('some-event', function(rooms) {
            ...
        });

});
```

You can read document links below:

1. [Configuring Socket.IO](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO)
2. [socket.io github site](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io)

Comment: I think the question is not about how to configure store